# How to parse xml and get specific element using SQL in db2 with verion DSN11015 database

Tags: database, db2

I am new to DB2 and request help in writing query for the below scenario.
I have a table XML_INTERFACE with column XML_FILE as XML type , XML file has the following format

```
<CalculationResponse><OBook specVersion="0161" timestamp="2017-04-05T05:55:06" ONumber="16191245" source="SOURCE" FNumber="00018956452345"><BrickItems><BrickItem ----
</BrickItems></OrderBook></CostCalculationResponse>
```

I want to extract specverion, ONumber, source, timestamp and FNumber using SQL.

I tried using the below query in DBVisualizer but does not work it just returns blank spaces:

```
select xmlquery('$doc/CalculationResponse/OBook/ONumber' 
passing cast(XML_FILE as XML) as "doc") from  XML_INTERFACE
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You may want to read about syntax of XPath expressions.